# How to make django not render html?

Tags: django

I have model:

```
class NewsItem(models.Model):
    meta_title = models.CharField(_('Meta title'), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True,
                              help_text=mark_safe('Tag <title>'))
```

But on the page I have:

```
<div class="form-row field-meta_title">
    <div>
        <label for="id_meta_title">Meta title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="meta_title" class="vTextField" maxlength="255" id="id_meta_title">
        <div class="help">Tag <title></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to tell django not render html?

Comment: Remove `mark_safe` from the help_text arg?

Comment: Well it does not *escape* the HTML. If it was escaping it, it would be `&lt;title&gt;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`mark_safe(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) tells Django *not* to escape the HTML. It will thus *not* translate `<` to `&lt;`, etc. and as a result, the HTML ends up as HTML code in the rendered output.

By omitting the `mark_safe(…)` part, you thus will render this as `Tag &lt;Title&gt;`, which will appear on the page as `Tag <title>`.

Django thus automatically escapes HTML content written as help text, values, etc. You should only use `mark_safe(…)` if you want to render the HTML as HTML content.